# Prevent Direct Access to pdf file? php, wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

How can i prevent direct access to my pdf file in wp-content/upload/woocommerce_upload folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www.)?domin.com/wp- 
content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/2020/01/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(pdf|jpe?g|png)$ - [F]
```

Its not working please help

Comment: Why are you trying to check for that specific referrer?

Answer (score 0):

why not use this?

```
<FilesMatch "/wp- 
content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/2020/01/.*\.pdf$">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I tried this out but not working my pdf file is in folder but when i try to access it directly it stills display pdf file

Comment: There should be another .htaccess down the path that overrides the permissions then

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help:  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files

it should be something like:

```
<Files "yourfilename.pdf">
Require all denied
</Files>
```

Comment: I tried this out but not working my pdf file is in folder but when i try to access it directly it stills display pdf file